# Importing libraries in Processing IDE

Tags: arduino, processing

I am sorry guys if I didnt make myself clear. So here is an another attempt.

I am trying to view the output of MPU6050 (gyrometer + acclerometer) in Processing IDE. I added the FreeIMU library in arduino and then executed the FreeIMU quaternion code from the examples. I was able to see the change in data values in the serial monitor of arduino. 
Now I wanted to see a graphical output using Processing IDE using FreeIMU Cube example. 
I am just not able to proceed furthur from here. 
Kindly provide me with the steps from here onwards. See video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gU9vM0UE3Ug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeIMU is not a Processing library by itself but an Arduino one. So including FreeIMU in a Processing project won't work because it is made to access specific hardware and collect data from specific gyroscope and accelerometer chips.

To visualize graphically data on a computer (PC) with Processing, you have to communicate with the Arduino where FreeIMU is installed, to collect the data.

The FreeIMU library package, available [here](http://www.varesano.net/projects/hardware/FreeIMU), have two Processing examples. If you look at the code provided you'll have your answer.

FreeIMU_yaw_pitch_roll Processing example :

```
Visualize orientation information from a FreeIMU device

INSTRUCTIONS: 
This program has to be run when you have the FreeIMU_serial
program running on your Arduino and the Arduino connected to your PC.
```

Comment: Can you please guide me with the steps so as to how to display the graphical output in processing ide using the freeimu_cube example ?

I am new to this, really stuck here for hours !! :(

arduino processing